# What's the point of complex option formula adjustments?

Tags: option-pricing

I had a discussion with a colleague of mine about the implications of risk modelling for the Gamestock/Wirecard cases in the recent weeks and that stock borrow rates could be an important risk factor at times, joint with the situation of different lending/borrowing fees.

This makes option pricing models potentially quite complex, having to solve optimal control problems in some cases. But what's the point if your average trader simply uses Black-Scholes (BS) and fudges all those real-wold problems like widening spreads, suddenly significant borrow rates, etc. etc. into the "risk-free rate" (with which we all can borrow and lend any amount, sure *cough*), the "volatility of the stock" (yeah, we all know about that one.) and so on?

Doesn't that render most of the body of mathematical research there useless, even if it starts taking more and more realistic assumptions?

Comment: Traders just add these bumps into the bs vols or borrow because they have a feel of how much of a bump makes sense based in other experiences. It's very useful to be able to do this when things are moving quickly, you don't have time to calculate all the specifics. If it's a slower market then it makes sense to model things more exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what's the point if your average trader simply uses Black-Scholes (BS)
> and fudges all those real-wold problems like widening spreads,
> suddenly significant borrow rates, etc. etc. into the "risk-free rate"
> (with which we all can borrow and lend any amount, sure cough), the
> "volatility of the stock" (yeah, we all know about that one.) and so
> on?

Keep in mind that not all options are equity options.  We also have interest rate swaptions, futures options, FX options, et cetera.  Equity options really have about the most "hair" because they come with so many difficult- or impossible-to-model events, as you note.

So, one point of the complicated option models is to deal with these cases that have more attainable precision.  In fact, it is a general principle that, the simpler a phenomenon is, the more complex one can make the mathematics successfully applied to it (think of quantum mechanical models of the helium atom versus, say, demographic research).

With all the "hair" on equity options, we need simple mathematics.  Here, Black Scholes is used but not really as a model *per se*.  Instead it is employed as a highly nonlinear transformation between option prices and an unobservable parameter that we happen to call implied volatility.  This helps create numbers that are more directly comparable between option contracts, since the option prices themselves exhibit extremely high dynamic ranges over various strikes.

Comment: I see. But then, thinking out of the box (and to the far extreme, I know) - if we don't even really attempt to build a model with economically meaningful variables (after all, implied volatility was originally intended to be the volatility of the underlying) for equity instruments, why go through the hassle with BS at all? Why not just have the option pay-off and fudge it together with some polynomial of order 4 or 5 in time/price space and just fit thise 16-25 constants until they fit?    [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] You can just as well to termstructures on these constants and it would be FAR easier to maintain and to calibrate. All the greeks etc. are also only meaningful if we actually assume the underlying asset's volatility is sigma, which we are apparently fine for the hedge (delta as the proportion of the UL is only right if the implied volatility is the same as the asset's volatility) but disagree with it being a direct metric, e.g. option vol is asset vol. I know, stuff is complex and so on, I also work a few years now already but after a lot of thinking I really had no good answer for that.

Comment: Good points! As to the polynomial, I was perhaps being a bit too glib.  I mean, there certainly is *some* real theory to BS, and it is not just an empirical nonlinear transform.  For example, you point out that it gives us delta.  In practice, equity hedging is expensive so all models' deltas all tend to be within the hedge error limits for options that are not close to expiration or long-dated.  In the latter cases, you do see a bit more of jump models or stochastic vol respectively.

Comment: Amusingly (and escaping the attention of almost all quants) our B-S formula implementations *all* use a polynomial approximation.  This is because there is no closed-form *error function" `erf()` or gaussian CDF $N(\cdot)$, so under the hood mathematical libraries are using a Chebyshev polynomial approximation to a transformed equivalent of `erf()`.

Comment: @Brian why does it matter how you calculate things that have no closed form. If the answer is correct it's irrelevant that you use a polynomial expansion.

Comment: @will  It doesn't really matter.  I just find it amusing apropos of not_sure95's mention of polynomial approximations.  These things *do* become significant to know when you have some complicated option model where solutions get expressed in, say, Bessel function values.

Comment: @BrianB thanks for your comment - true, that is funny. Now if there is awareness that for example real delta hedges would be too expensive here, are desks really taking this into consideration, e.g. try to include his into their pricing model or is it "Well, I have 30 years of market experience, I know how things used to be, so I take the BS price and add 19 cents because I feel like it"?

Comment: It is all done by computers these days, so there's definitely no "add 19 cents".  The market maker will have a book manager responsible for each name,  who will have a volatility surface model, a borrow cost model, a spread model and so on, each having a couple parameters tunable by humans.  Algorithms then do the quoting based on all that.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that was insightfull.